# Unable to check mx records for domains such as yahoo and outlooks etc

Tags: python, smtplib, mx-record

I am trying to write a python script which would check the authenticity of a mail ID from a csv file which has the whole list. 
I am doing these three check for every email ID

**1. Regex check**

```
regex = re.compile(
        r'^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$')
```

**2. Domain Check**

```
splitAddress = email.split('@')
domain = str(splitAddress[1])
records = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX')
mxRecord = records[0].exchange
mxRecord = str(mxRecord)
```

**3. SMTP conversation check**

```
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.set_debuglevel(0)
server.connect(mxRecord)
server.helo(server.local_hostname) 
server.mail('abc@bt.com')
code, message = server.rcpt(str(email))
server.quit()
```

The issues I am having with this is that it doesn't run on some of the domains like **Yahoo**,**Outlook** and some random domain from my lists is **pmrelocations.com**

The traceback error that I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mxrecord.py", line 41, in <module>
    server.helo(server.local_hostname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 404, in helo
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 369, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

You can check the complete code here: https://github.com/Rwarlock/mxrecordchecker/blob/master/mxrecord.py

I understand that this code needs optimizations but I am currently focusing on making it work and will optimize it once its completely coded with all real life checks being performed.

I am not getting any leads on how to resolve the issue. I am very beginner with all the SMTP and DNS things. Please guide as to how can I solve this problem.

Comment: It looks like you can't connect to your local hostname. Can you print the `server.local_hostname`? Maybe you have some firewall problems

Comment: Hey I printed server.local_hostname and got this result [10.1.0.126]

Comment: From the traceback, it looks like the connection is closed when you try to get a response from the SMTP server. The connection is established, but it closes when you send the `helo` command. The [`HELO`](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference.htm) command is a command that identifies a client. Probably, your host is not valid to connect to the SMTP server.

Comment: Hey @vtemian, I searched about it on the internet. I stumbled upon this answer : https://superuser.com/a/1293086 . Am I looking right?

Comment: Hi @vtemian, I Changed my code and was able to get yahoo working can you look at the question that I recently posted and help me out with outlook mails. here is the link to the queestion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54684917/11054558