# Not able to verify emails for Outlook server.mail() parameter issue

Tags: python, outlook, smtp, smtp-auth

This is in continuation with my last question [Unable to check mx records for domains such as yahoo and outlooks etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54670906/11054558) 
I am getting an exception

```
outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com.
mail() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

For Yahoo also I am getting the same exception

```
mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.
mail() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

---

My full code for the script verification is this: 
https://github.com/Rwarlock/mxrecordchecker/blob/master/mxrecord.py

What parameters should I use so that I can connect with this(outlook) domain?
What am I missing here?

---

**UPDATE**
I updated the parameters with ,

```
server.mail('bhanu@krenovate.com',email)
```

And Now I am getting this error:

```
outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com.
Connection unexpectedly closed
```

---

**Update 2** 
I was able to connect to yahoo but still unable to debug outlook.

```
outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com.
connect: ('outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com.', 25)
connect: ('outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com.', 25)
reply: '220 DB5EUR01FT021.mail.protection.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 14 Feb 2019 07:47:10 +0000\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: DB5EUR01FT021.mail.protection.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 14 Feb 2019 07:47:10 +0000
connect: DB5EUR01FT021.mail.protection.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 14 Feb 2019 07:47:10 +0000
send: 'helo www.outlook.com\r\n'
reply: '250 DB5EUR01FT021.mail.protection.outlook.com Hello [14.143.8.238]\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: DB5EUR01FT021.mail.protection.outlook.com Hello [14.143.8.238]
send: 'mail FROM:<bhanukrsingh@outlook.com>\r\n'
reply: '550 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Client host [14.143.8.238] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/[14.143.8.238] (AS3130). [DB5EUR01FT021.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com]\r\n'
reply: retcode (550); Msg: 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Client host [14.143.8.238] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/[14.143.8.238] (AS3130). [DB5EUR01FT021.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com]
send: 'rcpt TO:<bhanukrsingh@outlook.com>\r\n'
Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I am receiving this debug data.
Also one the testing domains in the list throws this

```
mail.pmrelocations.com.
connect: ('mail.pmrelocations.com.', 25)
connect: ('mail.pmrelocations.com.', 25)
reply: '451-The server has reached its limit for processing requests from your host. \r\n'
reply: '451 Please try again later.\r\n'
reply: retcode (451); Msg: The server has reached its limit for processing requests from your host.
Please try again later.
connect: The server has reached its limit for processing requests from your host.
Please try again later.
send: 'helo www.outlook.com\r\n'
Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Comment: Did you read the error message you got from the server?

Comment: Yes! It is limiting me or marking me as a spam. How can I fix that? Is it doable?

Comment: If you know the admin, ask them to stop disliking you. Barring that, probably wait. This is not a programming problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you able to solve this?